# Prince Rupert's Ball?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science

So I have been thinking about a [Prince Rupert's Drop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Rupert's_Drop) and was wondering if a perfectly spherical version would be possible. For example, consider a piece of liquid glass in Zero-G, which is then surrounded by water. How strong would a ball like this be?

Comment: -1. This question lacks context and research effort. Probably an engineering question, and a duplicate of [Is it possible to build a perfectly spherical prince ruperts drop?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/100/) on Engineering SE.